# Prompting user for user credential right after the app installation

Tags: apex, appexchange, postinstall, install, external-app

Is it possible to ask for user input at the end of app installation? I need users to enter credentials for external API at the end of app installation or very beginning of an app.

Basically, I'm trying to do 3 things

1. Authenticate user when they install the app to send credentials and recieve access tokens
2. Schedule jobs to make API requests to receive data from external server.
3. Check if that data is ready on an external server and reschedule job if it is not ready.

Are all these things possible in Salesforce app? If yes, it would be great if you can lay out what you know about them.

Sorry the questions go out of that scope of the title and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe use the ["Custom Link"](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_uploading.htm) option on your managed package.

I'd guess you want custom settings to capture api credentials.

2. [Apex scheduler?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm). [Or batch apex?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm).
3. I don't think you can dynamically reschedule. Maybe just set the interval to be one that's acceptable.